# Python - short syntax for catching exceptions in expressions

Tags: python, exception, syntax, expression, syntactic-sugar

Is there a short syntax for catching and processing exception within expressions. E.g if we have some complex expression `eint(x)` and another one `eext(y)` would be nice to do:

```
print(
    eext(
        eint(x)
        ecatch (ValueError, AssertionError) as ex1 do f'Exception {ex1} for {x}!'
        ecatch IndexError as ex2 do f'Exception {ex2} for {x}!'
    )
)
```

where `LEFT ecatch(types, var) RIGHT` returns expression `LEFT` if no exception in LEFT, otherwise checks that exception is within `types` types, if so then exception value is assigned to `var` and `RIGHT` expression is evaluated and returned as a result of whole expression. If there is unhandled type of exception then exception is thrown from total expression that may (or may not) be also catched by some other `ecatch` expressions on the right.

Of cause such ecatch can be modeled by a simple function accepting lambdas:

```
def my_ecatch(left, extypes, right):
    try:
        return left()
    except extypes as ex:
        return right(ex)
```

but maybe there is some syntax sugar for doing that already in Python?

Same like lists processing can be also achieved by regular loops, but there exists list comprehension which can look nicer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no shorthand for this.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe there are some known proposals for that which can be included in later Python versions?

Comment: There was a proposal but was rejected. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/